# How to enhance contrast of images in AForge (like Photoshop's Auto-Constrast)

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing

I want to enhance slightly a contrast of a bitmap, usually I do this by loading the image in Photoshop and using Auto-Contrast or Auto-Tone. The task is to add some contrast (maybe enhance colors) to the light pictures.

How do I do something close to this using AForge? Or maybe there is some other 3rd party library which could be better used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use one of the AForge.NET colour correction filters.
For contrast adjustment, the usual technique would be a [histogram equalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization) or [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_%28image_processing%29).

Examples are in the AForge.NET documentation for [histogram equalization](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/ca3f38d2-8c09-70d4-b20f-830cca2f6d9b.htm) and [normalization](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/e7e63ac5-7c1b-5dc2-40b2-8c80e217a946.htm).

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to third party libraries, try [OpenCV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV). Here is an [example](http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/~noahKuntz/openCVTut5.html#Step%203) of adjusting contrast.